# A search method that finds a string value in an String Array

Tags: java

So I am trying to create a method that finds a title in a ArrayList of photos.

```
public class Album {

    private String albumtitle;
    private ArrayList<Photo> photos;

    /**
     * This constructor should initialize the
     * instance variables of the class.
     */
    public Album(String title) {

        this.albumtitle = title;
        photos = new ArrayList<>();

    }
```

This is the code I have got to for trying to search for a specific title of the photo. I am not sure if i should put `(int index)` or `(String title)` in the methods parameters.

```
public Photo searchByTitle(int index) {

        if (index >= 0 && index < photos.size()) {
            String title = photos.get(index);
            System.out.println(title);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am beginner programmer, and I feel a little guidance will help a lot.

**Edit:** So lots of people are telling me to use for loops. My project requires me to not do for loops for methods, hence why I have displayed it in this way.

I'll give you an example the lecturer gave us:

https://lms.uwa.edu.au/bbcswebdav/pid-1134902-dt-content-rid-16529804_1/courses/CITS1001_SEM-2_2018/lectures/BooksReadJournal.java.pdf

She doesn't use for loops.

Comment: What does your `Photo` class has? Are you searching for a photo in an album with the photo's title?

Comment: How are you planning on calling this method? `searchByTitle(17)`? or (more likely) `searchByTitle("The Song")`?

Comment: Did you execute the code? photos.get(index) should return a Photo, not a String

Comment: `String title` If you want to seachbyTitle. Iterate Album and try comparing `album.albumTitle` with search string

Comment: What will the user know more likely? The title or the index?

Comment: Either the name of method `public Photo searchByTitle(int index)` is just misleading, because you are looking up an entry by its index, or you have implemented the wrong search algorithm inside the method.

Comment: Follow the method name. If method is to searchByTitle, why would you expect it to receive the index?

Comment: Please note: "a little guidance" isn't exactly in the scope of this community. This is not a tutor service, where you drop your work, and others review it. You should rather ask a specific question, about things not working. See [mcve] for example.

Comment: With Java8 you could do `photos.stream().filter(p -> p.getTitle().equals(searchterm)).collect( Collectors.toList())` to get all photos whose title matches.

Comment: And hint: you should go `List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>()`... dont use the specific impl class as type, only the interface List!

Comment: I would suggest you to look Collection topic in Java.

Comment: What @aydinugur means. the collections trail from oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Answer (score 4):

You could use the stream-API:

```
Arrays.stream(photos).filter(p -> p.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(searchTitle)).findFirst().orElseGet(...);
```

You iterate over each photo called p in this array and compare p's title with the one you search and return the first match.

Or simply use a normal for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < photos.size(); i++) {
  if(photos[i].getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(searchTitle)){ return photos[i]; }
  return new ErrorPhoto(); //or some error state
}
```

More enhanced for-each-loop:

```
for(Photo p: photos) {
  if(p.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(searchTitle)) { return p; }
  return new ErrorPhoto(); //or some error state
}
```

Comment: added simple for loop

Answer (score 3):

You iterate over each photo and compare its title with the one you search and return the first match:

```
for(int i = 0; i < photos.size, i++) {
    if(photos.get(i).getTile().equals("title name"){
         System.out.println("Found the title");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current code will always return null. If this is a search method to return the found object, you return the object if it is found. If not found, then return null:

```
public Photo searchByTitle(String title) {    
    for(Photo p : photos)
        if(p.getTitle().equals(title))
            return p;
    return null;
}
```

> This is the code I have got to for trying to search for a specific title of the photo. I am not sure if i should put (int index) or (String title) in the methods parameters

Since the method name itself suggested `searchByTitle`, whoever is using this method would expect it to receive `String title`.

If it is to be searched by index, then there can be another method as such:

```
public Photo searchByIndex(int index){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for a search, either you look a `Photo` up by its title or by its index. If your class had both methods, it would look like this:

```
public class Album {

    private String albumtitle;
    private ArrayList<Photo> photos;

    /**
     * This constructor should initialize the instance variables of the class.
     */
    public Album(String title) {
        this.albumtitle = title;
        photos = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Searches the {@link Photo} with the given title.
     * @param title the title of the desired {@link Photo}
     * @return the {@link Photo} with the given title or 
     *  <code>null</code> if it is not in the list
     */
    public Photo searchByTitle(String title) {
        // initialize with null to return that if the photo was not found
        Photo photo = null;

        // iterate all photos and check if one of them has the title
        for (int i = 0; i < photos.size(); i++) {
            if (title.equals(photos.get(i).getTitle())) {
                photo = photos.get(i);
                // exit the loop when the photo was found
                break;
            }
        }

        return photo;
    }

    /**
     * Searches the {@link Photo} with the given index.<br>
     * Checks if the index is valid in the list of {@link Photo}s
     * @param index the index of the {@link Photo}
     * @return the {@link Photo} with the given index or <code>null</code> 
     *  if it is not in the list or the index is invalid.
     */
    public Photo searchByIndex(int index) {
        try {
            // use the method of the list to get the photo
            return photos.get(index);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioe) {
            // print some error message for the case of an invalid index
            System.err.println("The given index is not available!");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package simple;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Album {
private static String albumtitle;
public Album(String title) {
    Album.albumtitle = title;
}

public Photo searchByTitle(ArrayList<Photo> photos) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < photos.size()) {
        Photo title = photos.get(index);
        if (title.getTitle().equals(albumtitle))
            System.out.println("tile Found" + title);
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();
    //Searching title2 or u can pass as parameter
    Album album = new Album("title2");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Photo photo = new Photo();
        photo.setTitle("Title" + i);
        photos.add(photo);

    }
    album.searchByTitle(photos);

}
```

}

```
package simple;
public class Photo {
String title;
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

}

Are looking for this..?